# Why is first value of captured expression getting stored in fourth element in Perl?

Tags: perl, arrays

I am storing information captured by regex into an array. But for some reason the first value is getting stored at 4 element of array. Any suggestion on whats going wrong and how to store the first value in the first element of array.

The following is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
my @value;
my $find= qr/^\s+([0-9]+)\s+([A-Z])/;

open (FILE, "</usr/test")|| die "cant open file";
my @body=<FILE>;

foreach my $line (@body){
    chomp $line;
    push @value, join('', $line =~ /$find/);
}
print "$value[0]\n"; #does not print anything
print "$value[4]\n"; #prints first value i.e 1389E
exit;
```

*DATA*

```
   1389 E not
   188  S yes
   24   D yes
   456  K not
   2    Q yes
```

Answer (score 4):

Your second line has more than one space between the number group and the letter, so you probably want `\s+` both times rather than `\s` the second time.

You won't necessarily know how many items you have in the `@value` array at the end, so you might want to put the printing into a `for` loop rather than assume you have a fifth item. (Maybe you know you want the first and fifth, however?) **Follow-up**: based on your edit, you have more than two entries after all. The version that I give below, using `split` and `\s+` captures the number and letter for all the lines. I'll adjust the print part of the script to show you what I mean.

A few other things:

- You should always enable warnings.
- There's no reason to read the whole file into an array and then process through it line by line. Skip the `@body` array and just do what you need to in the `while` loop.
- Use the more modern form of `open` with lexical filehandles and three arguments.
- `split` seems more straightforward here to me, rather than a regular expression with captures. Since you want to capture two specific parts of the line, you can use `split` with an array slice to grab those two items and feed them to `join`.
- `@value` is not an especially helpful variable name, but I think you should at least make it plural. It's a good habit to get into, I think, insofar as the array stores your plural records. (That's not a hard and fast rule, but it bugged me here. This point is pretty minor.)

Here's how all this might look:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env perl
    use warnings;
    use strict;

    my @values;

    # open my $filehandle, '<', '/usr/test'
    #     or die "Can't open /usr/test: $!";

    while (my $line = <DATA>) {
        chomp $line;
        push @values, join('', (split /\s+/, $line)[1..2]);
    }

   for my $record (@values) {
      print $record, "\n";
    }

    __DATA__
       1389 E not
       188  S yes
       24   D yes
       456  K not
       2    Q yes
```

Comment: Shouldn't "... form of open with lexical filehandles and three arguments" be used in your code example? And a scope to go out of? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Peter: I can't actually use the `open` statement, since I don't have the OP's /usr/test file on my drive (and I'm not going to create it for this example). So I wrote the example to show him what I meant, but I use the built-in `__DATA__` to get the files. As far as "a scope to go out of", in a script this short, the problem isn't really scope per se. I wasn't stressing 'lexical' in lexical filehandles; that's just their name. See here for more on bareword filehandles: http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?bareword_uppercase_filehandles

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be writing

```
print "$value[0]\n";
print "$value[4]\n";
```

to access elements of an array.

Comment: @David: I wrote @value[0] by mistake. I am using $value[0] to print the first value of the array. And, no value is getting printed for first element i.e. $value[0]

Answer (score 1):

You should use lexical file handles and the three argument form of [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) as well as avoiding slurping files unnecessarily.

In any case, the most likely reason for your problem is a single character missing from your pattern. Compare the one below with the one you have above.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @value;
my $find= qr/^\s+([0-9]+)\s+([A-Z])/;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    last unless $line =~ /\S/;
    push @value, join '', $line =~ $find;
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@value;

__DATA__
   1389 E not
   188  S yes
   24   D yes
   456  K not
   2    Q yes
```

Comment: @Sinan: my bad, of not using '\s+' instead of '\s'. But, still first value is being printed on printing the first element of array.

Comment: @shubster Figure out what's different between the code/data above and the code/data you don't show us.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have leading whitespace lines, or other leading lines in your data that don't match your regexp? Since you're unconditionally push()-ing onto your output array, regardless of whether your regexp matches, you'll get blank array elements for every non-matching line in your input.

Observe:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines;

while (<DATA>) {
  push @lines , ( join( '' , /^\s*(\d+)/ ));
}

foreach ( 0 .. $#lines ) {
  print "$_ -> $lines[$_]\n";
}


__DATA__
FOO
Bar
Baz
   1234
456
bargle
```

Output:

```
0 -> 
1 -> 
2 -> 
3 -> 1234
4 -> 456
5 ->
```